# Angular pass templateRef to child component

Tags: angular

I have a piece of code that used to work in Angular 9 and now with Angular 12 it does not anymore. I think I need somehow to use ngTemplateOutletContext.

parent component:

```
<ng-template #navTemplate>
  <a *ngFor="let link of links">{{link}}</a>
</ng-template>
<child-component>
  [navTemplate]="navTemplate"
</child-component>
```

child component (ts):

```
@Input() navTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

child component (html)

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="navTemplate"></ng-container>
```

If instead of passing as template a list of item that depends on a variable. So for example if I pass a simple div it works. So I assume the problem is that the variable `links` needs somehow to be passed to the child component.

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in stackblitz?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"

Comment: @Antoniossss basically the template renders, but there is nothing in the ngFor

Comment: `links` is empty then iguess

Comment: In stackblitz it works.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-beckn5?file=src/app/app.component.ts
The problem must be with storybook then.

Comment: As @Antoniossss said, links is empty. Just add *ngIf="links?.length" to the <child-component> and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access links in your template, you need to add it to the ngTemplateOutletContext.

```js
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="navTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="links"></ng-container>
```

This requires that you also pass links from the parent to child component via property binding.

```js
<child-component> [navTemplate]="navTemplate" [links]="links" </child-component>
```

Finally your template must look like this:

```js
<ng-template #navTemplate let-links="links">
      <a *ngFor="let link of links">{{link}}</a>
    </ng-template>
```